# How last_id works?

Tags: php, mysql

The customer sql is inserted the others are not. Help. Thanksss

I have sql for customer_tbl, transaction_tbl, and order_tbl.

customer_no, transaction_no and orderlist_no are A_I.

This is my code so far.

```
 $x=0;
 while ($x!=5) {
    $product_sku[$x] = $_POST['productsku[$x]'];
    $quantity[$x] = $_POST['productqty[$x]'];
    $x=$x+1;
 }

 $sqlc = "INSERT INTO customer_tbl(customer_name, fb_url, mobile_no, email_address, address) VALUE ('$customer_name', '$fb_url', '$mobile_no', '$email', '$address');";

 mysqli_query($conn, $sqlc);
 $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);


 $sqlt = "INSERT INTO transaction_tbl(customer_no, transaction_type, status, transaction_date, deadlinepay_date, payment_mode, delivery_option) VALUE ('$lastid', 'OL-', '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '$deadlinepay_date', '$payment_mode', '$shipping_option');";

 mysqli_query($conn, $sqlt);
 $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

 $x=0;
 while ($x!=5) {
    if (!empty($product_sku[$x])) {
        $sqlo = "INSERT INTO order_tbl(transaction_no, product_sku, quantity) VALUES ('$last_id', '$product_sku', '$quantity');";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sqlio);
    }
    $x=$x+1;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you have `$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);` but in your query, you have `...VALUE ('$lastid'...`.

So change `$lastid` to `$last_id` or the other way around.

You should keep naming your variables consistent to avoid confusion in the future.